# str.contain "\" should only be used as an escape character outside of raw strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have a dataframe with one column and i want to know if the value of the column contain a "+". I made like this:

```
mask = df['column'].str.contains("\+")
```

But when I execute the sonarqube analysis throws me a bug ("" should only be used as an escape character outside of raw strings).

I tried to change the line of code to this:

```
mask = df['column'].str.contains(r"+")
```

But throws me an error:

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

How can i make the same as the first line without the error??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between escaping the characters in python to be interpreted as a special character (e.g. `\n` is a newline and has nothing to do with `n`), and escaping the character not to be interpreted as a special symbol in the regex. Here you need both.

Either use a raw string:

```
mask = df['column'].str.contains(r'\+')
```

or escape the backslash:

```
mask = df['column'].str.contains('\\+')
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['abc', 'ab+c']})

df['column'].str.contains(r'\+')

0    False
1     True
Name: column, dtype: bool
```

Comment: If both need to be done, wouldn't the correct code be `r'\\+'` or `'\\\\+'` ?

Comment: There are two levels of parsing here: Python the string, and `re` the pattern. The `r"..."` is necessary for Python to parse the string as is, and the `\` is necessary for the regex engine to escape the `+`

Comment: @Flimm No, here you would do it one extra time. Maybe my phrasing wasn't clear, you need a backslash to tell the regex to ignore the `+` as a repeating character. Thus the regex is `\+`. But python would interpret `\x` as an escape code so you tell python to use a literal backslash: `'\\'` or `r'\'`

Comment: @Tomerikoo and you need another level of parsing for the markdown language :p

Comment: Upvoted, because this should solve the problem. But I don't think this has anything to do with the regex. This is static code analysis saying that `\+` is not a valid escape sequence (which is correct). But python knows this, and so reads `\+` as a literal sequence of two characters (as it would for an r-string). Whereas, other languages might crash or refuse to compile.

Comment: @Dunes it is true that my python version doesn't raise the issue and `'\+'` should remain literal as it is not a valid escape code, but I don't know in which context the error was triggered in OP's setup (which python version, interpreter...).

Comment: Op mentions sonarqube, which is what is doing the complaining. It's not python or the re module that have an issue with Op's first code fragment.

Comment: @Dunes I see, I didn't know this tool. Then that makes sense, the code wouldn't have raised an error in this particular case, but the character should have been escaped anyway

Comment: Or perhaps in this case... don't worry about escaping and be explict to contains you're not wanting a regex... eg: `df["column"].str.contains("+", regex=False)`